How to get IPictureDisp type object in Python?
I am migrating VBA code to Python, and there is a need to create an IPictureDisp object from image (.BMP) in Python.
How do I get an image of such a type (IPictureDisp) in Python?
Migrating VBA to Python script.
Tried pywin32 package, and PIL packages but no luck.
